# Not seeing a toilet shut off valve for installing bidet

Tags: plumbing, water, toilet

I live in an apartment and it seems like every toilet has a connection like this.

To install my bidet I need to shut off the valve, but I'm not seeing one here?

Is there a way to shut off the water to the toilet with this setup or will I need to find the main line.

[image]

Comment: are you sure that's not a valve? Looks like the "handle" pulls instead of twists. Why have a screw if the part doesn't move at all? Can we get a close-up of that "handle"? Worst case you can freeze the pipe with a can of dust-off long enough to slap a tee on. You also might be able to kink that flexible line shut and splice it instead of the PVC.

Comment: I use dry ice around a pipe to freeze them similar to Dan’s comment above. Can we get a photo horizontally of that valve just below the circle, it looks like some kind of valve to me also, maybe a close up on the writing on top? It looks like a glue-less type of fitting because of the size at the bottom but I haven’t seen a shark bite like that. It could be 1/4 turn I have seen them more often in plastics type of valves.

Answer (score 4):

That's a "PUSHON" toilet supply valve like this:
[image]
<sub>https://accortechnology.com/pushon-r-series-sink-lavatory-supply-kit-1-2-valve-x-1-2-ips-nut</sub>

If you go to their install video here: https://youtu.be/5DRQZuLR9y4 and skip to about 2:55 you'll see that to shut the valve off you pull on the knob and to turn it back on you push the knob back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ad a valve and/or a secondary connection for a bidet then you will need to shut the water supply off to that pipe. The pipe is PVC, you can use a glue on valve or a push to connect valve.

It may be a push to connect fitting and if so removable without cutting the pipe, if not you need to cut it off just below it to leave as much pipe above the floor as possible.

Once your new valve(s) are installed you can turn the water back on, but if the supply lines have not yet been connected to the valves make sure they are in the **closed position**.

You will need a new supply line to go from the new valve to the toilet. (*and of coarse a line for the bidet.*)